# java.lang.StackOverflowError for BufferedReader with custom class

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

This is the custom class which I made:

```
class BufferedReader{
    BufferedReader inClient = null;

    public BufferedReader(InputStreamReader stream) {
        inClient = new BufferedReader(stream); //points the stackoverflow on this line
    }
    public String readLine(){
        return inClient.readLine();
    }
}
```

So, when I try to access it like below I end up getting a stackoverflow:

```
BufferedReader[] inClient = new BufferedReader[2];

//using a socket here
inClient[0] = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You should never define classes having the same names as JDK classes. Try renaming your class to something different.

Comment: @soufrk, Thanks! Changing the class name solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This gives you a `StackOverflowError` because you have uncontrolled recursion due to the naming you're using. The constructor will keep calling itself until the stack overflows.

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you reallocate a new instance of your class which reallocates a new instance of your class... infinitely until you reach the maximum stack size which generates a StackOverflowError.

You should rename your class not to be confused with the one from Java or if you want to keep the name you have to use the full name of the JDK class in your constructor and in the attribute definition: java.io.BufferedReader